# Adding mime type handler

Tags: mime-types, firefox-os

I want do develop an app for Firefox OS that should handle tickets inside *.pkpass files.

The problem is, there seems to be no way to get a pkpass file from an email if it's attached as an attachment nor does the browser allows me to download it directly so the only way would be is to download it from the app directly which is, for my application, pretty much negating the purpose of an app (tickets are delivered using email and are not publicly available online, so the end user would need to download a ticket from an email and open it using the application which will verify-unpack it and store the data in a separate data storage).

Is there any way to download it to a device without using an app? Or it's not currently possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, default email app of Firefox OS cannot open attachments without images or photos. The browser also limits download for security issues. But, your app can register [WebActivities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Activities) and handle file directly.

```
{
  // Other App Manifest related stuff

  // Activity registration
  "activities": {

    // The name of the activity to handle (here "pick")
    "view": {
      "href": "./view.html",
      "disposition": "inline",
      "filters": {
        "type": ["application/vnd.apple.pkpass"]
      },
      "returnValue": true
    }
  }
}
```

You can refer usages of [File manager app](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/file-manager) too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've looked into this, but this still doesn't solve the problem of transferring the file to the phone. If the attachment can't be opened using e-mail application it practically means it can only be downloaded to the phone using browser (directly from mails web front-end) which doesn't work either.
Or does registering an application means that the file will be available to download from the browser?